# Split a string by different start and end delimiters

Tags: python

I have a log with data from a TCP port with a given buffer length. Each event has a variable length and it is delimited by <+++> and <--->.

Example:

```
s = '<+++>A1 , Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text<---> 
<+++>A2, Some Text, IP=0.0.0.0, DateTime=12/07/2018 <---> <+++> A3, Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text,
Text<---><+++>A3, New Text, IP=0.0.0.0, DateTime=12/07/2018, Text3Text3Text3, Text3Text3Text3, Text3Text3Text3,
Text3Text3Text3<--->Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4 
Text4<---><+++>Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5<---><+++>Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6<--->'
```

I need to split it so that each event is the element of a list -- like this:

```
['A1 , Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text' , 'A2, Some Text, IP=0.0.0.0, DateTime=12/07/2018', 'A3, Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text']
Text']
```

How would you do this with Python?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but can't you split by <+++> then by <---> and remove the empty values from the list?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Answer (score 13):

You can also use regular expressions for this task, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) in particular:

```
import re
s = '<+++>A1 , Some Text, Other Text=12327463<---> <+++>A2, IP=0.0.0.0 <--->'
re.findall(r'<\+\+\+>(.+?)<--->', s)
# ['A1 , Some Text, Other Text=12327463', 'A2, IP=0.0.0.0 ']
```

The captured group `(.+?)` stands for one or more (`+`) of any character (`.`) non-greedily (`?`) matched, so as to not capture the entire part from the first opening to the last closing tag.

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
s= '<+++>A1 , Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text<---> <+++>A2, Some Text, IP=0.0.0.0, DateTime=12/07/2018 <---> <+++> A3, Some Text, Other Text=12327463, Some Other Text, Text<---><+++>A3, New Text, IP=0.0.0.0, DateTime=12/07/2018, Text3Text3Text3, Text3Text3Text3, Text3Text3Text3, Text3Text3Text3<--->Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4Text4 Text4<---><+++>Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5Text5<---><+++>Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6Text6<--->'
s = s.replace('<--->','')
t = s.split('<+++>')
print (t)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it pretty simply, I'd just use a couple of steps. It looks, in this case, that we can assume that the string *always* starts with "<+++>" and ends with "<--->". So, we can simply strip them from the string and use a simple `string.split`:

```
temp = s[len("<+++>") : -len("<--->")]
return temp.split("<---><+++>")
```

If the problem is more complicated, you could also look into using regular expressions with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
def multi_split(s, sep):
    stack = [s]
    for char in sep:
        pieces = []
        for substr in stack:
            pieces.extend(substr.split(char))
        stack = pieces
    return stack
```

usage: `multi_split(string,separators)` where sep can be a single char, a list of strings, a tuple. In your case `['<--->','<+++>']`

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friends.

```
import re
res = re.compile('\<...\>').split(s)
```

and then you have to clear the empty strings from your list.

```
res = list(filter(None, res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
start, end = '<+++>', '<--->'
[item for item in (item.strip().strip(start) for item in s.split(end)) if item]
```

`s` is the value of `s` in the question code.

Answer (score 0):

You can split then join then split

```
new = s.split('<+++>')
new = ''.join(new)
new = new.split('<--->')

print(new)
```

or even:

```
new = s.split('<+++>').
new = ''.join(new).split('<--->')
```